# Heroku app having Mysql database on CleasDB very slow

Tags: mysql, django, heroku, cleardb

I have uploaded my MySql data base to a ClearDb server 
since then, the website (which right now is running locally and is not uploaded yet )
is super slow! I even upgraded the ClearDb account by still , very slow
does someone have a solution ? thanks

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.